# Gmail not working in chrome..

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I am trying to open my gmail account. I am not able to. I am getting this error:

```
This site can’t be reached

mail.google.com refused to connect.
Try:
Reloading the page
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Other services are working fine.

One thing I have observed is, when I tried to open gmail in IE, its default language was portuguise(Brasil). When I tried to change it to English, I am getting this error in IE:

```
 The webpage cannot be found 
 HTTP 404  
 Most likely causes:
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.

   What you can try: 
     Retype the address.  

     Go back to the previous page. 

     Go to  and look for the information you want.  

     More information
```

I have tried clearing browser data. Chrome is up-to-date. So what might be the problem.. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry this isn't really a programming question so it will be deleted. You may get better advice on the SuperUser site

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is to *remove* chrome and *install a previous* version and see if that helps. We had a similar scenario a few months ago and that sorted the problem out.

Comment: But! How to install previous version?

Comment: Please follow these links:
http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php
http://support.imonggo.com/help/kb/browser/how-to-install-a-previous-version-of-chrome-for-windows

We are currently running on Version 48.0.2564.82 m (64-bit) and we are not experiencing any of the issues we had.